# How to write in mathmode like attached figure

Tags: subscripts

I want to write `$x_{i}$` and under `$x$` `$i \in A$`. How to do this? I tried
`$x_i_{ i \in {I}}$`. But it is not working. I want like the attached figure.

[image]

Comment: Is it an `x` or the Greek letter `χ`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\mathop{<math>}` to make `<math>` a big operator which can accept a/an (extra) subscript even when `<math>` already has a subscript.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\verb|\substack|:
\[
  abc + \substack{x_i\\_{i\in I}} + abc
\]

\verb|\mathop|:
\[
  abc + \mathop{x_i}_{i \in I} + abc
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [egreg's `\underset`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/622593) is better.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\substack`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\substack{x_i\\_{i\in I}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\underset`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
a+\underset{i\in I}{x_i}+b
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You might want to add `\scriptscriptstyle` to make the subscript smaller:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
a+\underset{\scriptscriptstyle i\in I}{x_i}+b
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not sure what such a symbol would mean, but it's up to you.

Note: `\mathop` is *not* the correct way to do it, because the spacing around the symbol might turn out to be wrong.